# Two or More Django Projects in Same Droplet via Subdomain

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I have two django projects. When the person visits, www.example.com I want django project A to be served.

When the person visits, say, blog.example.com, I want django project B to be served.

How can I achieve that using nginx and gunicorn, configuration-wise?

I'm done with the subdomain DNS setup. I need help in the nginx-gunicorn aspect of serving the pages.

I used the One Click install of django by DO, so if the configuration could be along the lines of their setup, will be great.

No idea if this question belongs here or serverfault.

Comment: This post is likely to be closed as too broad, but I highly recommend Michał Karzyński's post on [Serving multiple Django applications with Nginx and Gunicorn](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/10/29/serving-multiple-django-applications-with-nginx-gunicorn-supervisor/).

Comment: @rnevius Thanks. But I think its a specific question directed towards configuration with regards nginx and gunicorn. Nothing more. Unless that's also too broad. I'm definitely checking you link.

Comment: You basically need to duplicate the configuration files that DO setup. Which are: `/etc/init/gunicorn.conf`, `/etc/nginx/sites-available/django.conf` and the `gunicorn.py` that `gunicorn.conf` points to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The principle is to use nginx as a broker for the HTTP requests, proxying them to two gUnicorn instances running your two Django apps in parallel, depending on their `Host` header.

For that you need to setup two different server configurations with nginx. Each with a different `server_name`. Those two servers will proxy to two different gUnicorn instances running on different ports.

**Nginx configuration**

```
# Server definition for project A
server {
    listen             80;
    server_name        <projectA domain name>;

    location / {
        # Proxy to gUnicorn.
        proxy_pass             http://127.0.0.1:<projectA gUnicorn port>;
        # etc...
    }
}

# Server definition for project B
server {
    listen             80;
    server_name        <projectB domain name>;

    location / {
        # Proxy to gUnicorn on a different port.
        proxy_pass             http://127.0.0.1:<projectB gUnicorn port>;
        # etc...
    }
}
```

It might be better to split the two definitions in separate files. Also remember to link them in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`.

**Upstart configuration**

These two files need to be put in `/etc/init/`.

`projecta_gunicorn.conf`:

```
description "Gunicorn daemon for Django project A"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

# If the process quits unexpectadly trigger a respawn
respawn

setuid django
setgid django
chdir /home/django/<path to projectA>

exec /home/django/<path to project A virtualenv>/bin/gunicorn --config /home/django/<path to project A gunicorn.py> <projectA name>.wsgi:application
```

`projectb_gunicorn.conf`:

```
description "Gunicorn daemon for Django project B"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

# If the process quits unexpectadly trigger a respawn
respawn

setuid django
setgid django
chdir /home/django/<path to projectB>

exec /home/django/<path to projectB virtualenv>/bin/gunicorn --config /home/django/<path to projectB gunicorn.py> <projectB name>.wsgi:application
```

**gUnicorn configuration**

Project A `gunicorn.py`:

```
bind = '127.0.0.1:<projectA gUnicorn port>'
raw_env = 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<projectA name>.settings'
```

Project B `gunicorn.py`:

```
bind = '127.0.0.1:<projectB gUnicorn port>'
raw_env = 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<projectB name>.settings'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Gradually taking me there. I have all configured and going well, except for the fact that, I get an Nginx Bad Gateway when I visit the, say, blog.example.com
The www.example.com works well. But the subdomain one complains of bad gateway of nginx. I'm still looking into why, perhaps made an error somewhere. If you've got any hints, please.

Comment: It means that nginx cannot proxy the request to gUnicorn, is the gUnicorn instance running? If yes, is it running on the port specified in the `proxy_pass`  of the nginx configuration?

Comment: Rechecking now. I think one of them might be the culprit.

Comment: You know what, its working now. You know what the culprit was? **sudo reboot** was what I needed. After rechecking and rechecking, I realized everything is perfect, until I remembered stuffs in /etc/init/* are loaded ONLY after reboot. Thanks for the answer. Exactly the kinda guidance I was looking for.

Comment: You could also have runned `service project[a or b]_gunicorn start`! You will have to run `service project[a or b]_gunicorn reload` if you want changes you made to a project to be taken into account.

Comment: I had thought that service gunicorn restart would have restarted all the instances. I was wrong. Good tip there. However it took less that 10 to restart whole vps. But will use your approach next time.